# with:100% only way to control centering button?

Tags: css, button, positioning

Having an issue I don't understand. The only way I've been able to center a button on my page perfectly across all devices is if I apply a width: 100% to it.

Issue with this however, is it then makes a sprawling button, way too wide. I'd like to cut it down. The problem is, anytime I get rid of the width: 100% in any way, it makes the perfect button position go haywire.

Any thoughts on how I can have my button centered, but also not super wide and sprawled out. Thank you. -Wilson

link to site: http://www.wilsonschlamme.com/test3.html?

CSS:

```
img {
width:100%;
max-width:500px;
max-height:340px;
box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px grey;
border-style: groove;
border-width: 1px;
position: absolute;
top: 107px;
}


button {
color: #900;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 150%;
text-transform: uppercase;
width: 100%;
position: relative;

top: 600px;


}



#ShowText{
width: 800px; /* change to your preferences */
overflow:hidden; /* older browsers */
position: absolute;
margin-top: 500px;
text-align: center;
margin-left: -140px;
font-size: 18px;
font-family: vendetta, serif;
line-height: 25px;

}

h1{
position: absolute;
top: 5px;
font-size: 250%;
width: 800px; /* change to your preferences */
overflow:hidden; /* older browsers */
font-family: hobeaux-rococeaux-sherman, sans-serif;

}


#wrapper {
width: 500px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this site there's a complete guide to centering a div.
http://www.tipue.com/blog/center-a-div/

Comment: Please [do not post an answer that consists essentially of a link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer). Include the important points in your answer; leave the link for extra information or as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's your base using absolute positioning for mostly of your element, but to answer your issue, give text-align:center; to #wrapper, then give text-align:left for each of #wrapper children, except the button.

Comment: My base is, my lack of knowledge. I'm extremely new to development. I saw an example of it being used. I'll give that a shot, thank you.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on what you mean by each of the #wrapper "children?"

Comment: Ok, just a reminder for styling, not to depend on absolute positioning for everything, since it'll be hard to maintain, especially later if you're doing responsive. also, if you determine the button width (not auto which is the default value of width attribute or 100% like in your case), then you can add margin: 0 auto; to that button